# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to load glass GTK library

Tags: compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

I develop compose multi-platform applications both android and desktop. My applications show HTML page. I use javafx.scene.web.WebView for webview. My application works properly android, mac and windows. But when i try to run application on ubuntu. I get this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to load glass GTK library.
> at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$new$5(GtkApplication.java:175)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
> at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.(GtkApplication.java:162)
> at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:40)
> at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
> at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:290)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:292)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
> at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.lambda$initFx$1(JFXPanel.java:230)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Yes i installed gtk 2 and gtk 3 but it does not work. I did not find how to fix this problem.

**Ubuntu version: 22.04.2 ARM64**

Have you ever encountered a problem like this before?

Comment: For debugging, add `-Djdk.gtk.verbose=true`. Then, JavaFX will output something like "checking GTK version 3
trying GTK library libgtk-3.so.0
trying GTK library libgtk-3.so"